# R linear model for twitter data

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, interpretation, lm

I'm trying to find if any relationship exists between the number of times a tweet is retweeted on Twitter and the number of likes it has.

I have a data frame with two columns retweet_count and likes_count.

I'm trying to fit a linear regression model using R with the likes_count and retweet_count and plot a linear fit.

And then using this linear fit to predict the number of likes the tweet will generate if retweeted 0,10,1000 times.

So far, I have done the following from the sources available online.

```
comb <- subset(combined_record, select=c("retweets_count", "likes_count"))
  
linearMod <- lm(retweets_count ~ likes_count, data=comb) 

print(linearMod)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  likes_count  
 -1284.2340       0.6101
```

And the prediction:

```
pred<-predict(linearMod, data.frame(likes_count = c(10)))
print(pred)

        1 
-1278.133
```

I'm not sure about how to read the outputs and my understanding of the flow of sequence. Would need some help in this context.

Comment: Such a model assumes a linear relationship between the two variables. Did you inspect the joint distribution of those variables using, e.g., a scatterplot? Then I would suggest to refine your question in order to highlight where you're stuck with linear regression *per se*, and to provide additional information (descriptive statistics) about your dataset. Linear regression, from basic to advanced techniques, is largely covered on this site; just browse the associated tag.

Comment: I want o what does negative intercept mean here? Is my code correct?

Comment: Your code looks fine but you didn't address my question, so we do not know if such a model is interpretable or not. In any case, the intercept reflect the expected value of y when x = 0.